# durandal starter kit search feature and IE

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I have taken the durandal starter kit and have attempted to use the search box.
In shell.html I have changed the input box to have a databinding to searchTerm:

```
 <form class="navbar-search pull-right" data-bind="submit:search">
 <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" data-bind="value:searchTerm">
 </form>
```

Then in shell.js I have added the observable searchTerm with this code:

```
define(function(require) {
    var router = require('durandal/plugins/router'),
    app = require('durandal/app');   

var searchTerm = ko.observable();
return {
    searchTerm: searchTerm,
    router: router,
    search: function() {

        app.showMessage('Search for ' + searchTerm() + ' not yet implemented');

    },
    activate: function () {
        return router.activate('welcome');
    }
 };
});
```

This code works in every browser ( well, Chrome, Firefox, Safari) except IE (9 and 10). The problem is that for IE, searchTerm() is always undefined. I am having the same problem in my production app but was able to reproduce it with this simple case. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form class="navbar-search pull-right" data-bind="submit:search">
 <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" data-bind="value:searchTerm, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
 </form>
```

Your input box needs to end with /> to be valid.  Also, add valueUpdate to your data-bind so that the change is recorded before your form submission.

http://jsfiddle.net/gnKth/1/

Comment: If you remove the submit button the fiddle has the same problem. By hitting enter on the text input the form gets submitted but the knockout binding does not occur.https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/760

Comment: ?  I left the /> off of the end, http://jsfiddle.net/gnKth/2/ I remove the button and add the />  and press enter and it clearly updates for me?  If nothing else update the value on key press like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gnKth/3/

Comment: If you change the value of 'hey2' in the text box it won't update in IE on submission.

Comment: Looks like we were working on this at the same time. The third fiddle had the answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known issue for IE. https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/760
Here is the fiddle from Sanderson himself.

http://jsfiddle.net/5StjB/1/

The workaround is to tell knockout to bind the values after each key down:

```
<input type="text" name="searchValue" data-bind="value: searchValue, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
```